# Unable to fetch id valuse in Java script

Tags: javascript, java, html, ember.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Nmy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aShpY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP3IF.png)

Hi there,
I am trying to create two buttons save and update where the difference between them is the save button will save the data navigate to the back page and the update button will save the data and will stay on the same page.
I am not sure where I am going wrong but I am unable to fetch the id in the if condition of Java Script.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include ALL relevant **code** (not pictures) in the question - pictures of very obscure snippets of code do not make for a good question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.